# Creating a custom Stackpanel with Transparent "Windows"

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, wpf-controls

Good evening.  I have been researching my issue for about two days now, and have tried at least a dozen variations of the problem.  Every single last one of them has been a complete total failure, so I won't bother posting any code here.

What I need is a StackPanel for a Border-less Window.  The StackPanel needs to have an opaque background, and the children need to have a transparent background.  I need the transparency to carry ALL the way through the child element, StackPanel, and underlying main window.

Does anyone have any idea as to how to go about this, and where I should start? I am an intermediate level programmer, and have hit a solid wall here. I have tried to inherit from Panel Class, over-riding the usual suspects; MeasureOverride, ArangeOveride, OnRender, etc..

One of the thoughts I also had, was using some form or another of CombinedGeometry between the parent, and all child nodes.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean when you say "the StackPanel needs to have an **opaque** background". Don't you want to have complete transparency through the complete element tree? Or in other words, if you have TextBlock with some text, you see that text and nothing else on top of the desktop (and other windows of course)?

Comment: Ok, here's the deal. I am creating a whiteboard app (out of necessity.)  I have a few items all inside a stack panel. At the top is a menu. At the bottom is a palette with controls. In the center is a "white board." The white board must have complete transparency through to the underlying Application, primarily PDF. I need the area surrounding the board containing the controls to be filled in, and not transparent. Does this make more sense?

Comment: I still don't get where the problem is. A StackPanel, or any other Panel, is already transparent unless you explicitly set its Background property. No problem. You can also overlay this Panel on top of any other (PDF viewer?) control. No problem, too. For the whiteboard items, what are they? Path, for example, is also transparent, unless it has a closed geometry and you set its Fill property. Still no problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you are probably missing is [`Window.AllowsTransparency="True"`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.allowstransparency%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Sad to say that you have to build your own window title and border because `WindowStyle` property must be set to `None`.

I've created a sample for you:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        AllowsTransparency="True"
        Background="Transparent"
        WindowStyle="None"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">        
        <DockPanel>
            <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                <MenuItem Header="Application">
                    <MenuItem Header="_Close" Click="MenuItem_Click"/>
                </MenuItem>
            </Menu>
            <ToolBar DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
                <Button>sample button</Button>
            </ToolBar>
            <StackPanel>
                ... your whiteboard ...
            </StackPanel>
        </DockPanel>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

.

```
private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: Ok, so maybe I need to get a bit "graphic" with this before I make a complete and total idiot out of myself. Here is a link to a picture of the app in action that I put together. (http://studiocc.elementfx.com)  What I need is a panel to put this entire mess into, that will have a black background, while still allowing the white board to be transparent. If I set the stackpanel that has everything right now, the underlying app is blocked out.

Comment: I posted another pic on my site. (http://studiocc.elementfx.com) The last suggestion did not work. I'm beginning to wonder if what i'm after is even possible.  As you can see, i've lost the transparency of my board. I have my container filled in now as I wanted, but no transparency.  Any other ideas?  Thanks!! CC

Comment: How you've lost transparency? You have several layers (in my example window, border, dockpanel, stackpanel). If one layer is not transparent you can not see what's below.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after many, MANY, hours of brute force "hacking," I have managed to figure out a means to accomplish what I need.

```
<Border Name="OuterBorder" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" BorderBrush="Orange" BorderThickness="1.5">
    <Border Name="FillerStrip" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="20">
        <Border Name="InnerBorder" BorderBrush="Orange" BorderThickness="1.5">
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Transparent">
                <local:GlassBoardControl BorderBrush="Orange"            BorderThickness="2" AxisBrush="LawnGreen" AxisThickness="15" x:Name="screen" />

            </StackPanel>
        </Border>    
    </Border>
</Border>
```

Now my only question is how on earth do I go about creating a custom panel with this as it's border?  Any ideas as to where I should start would be much appreciated.